# I cannot figure out why this simple Javascript will not work. Can anyone shed some light?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a travel calculator, here is the HTML, which all works fine with the CSS styling I have attached to it. No issues here.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
        <title>Travel Calculator 2.0</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css"/>
    </head>

    <body>
      <div class="container-fluid">
          <div id ="travel_calculator" class="row row-eq-height">
            <div id ="common_and_results" class="col-sm-4 order-sm-4 pb-5 pt-3">
              <div id ="results" class="card mb-3">
                <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1920x1080" alt="placeholder" class="card-img">
                <div class="card-img-overlay">
                  <h1 class="card-title text-white h2">Change Options</h1>
                </div>
                  <div class="col-12">
                    <div class="card bg-info mb-3">
                      <div class="form-group card-body">
                        <label class="h6" for="pay_rate">Pay Rate (assuming 8hr/day)</label>
                        <div id="pay-rate-group" class="input-group">
                          <div class="input-group-prepend">
                            <span class="input-group-text">
                              <i class="fa fa-money"></i>
                            </span>
                            <input class="form-control" name="pay_rate" type="number"
                            id="pay_rate" max="80" min="8" step="1" value="15">
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group card-body">
                        <label class="h6" for="travelers">Travelers</label>
                        <div id="travelers-group" class="input-group">
                          <div class="input-group-prepend">
                            <span class="input-group-text">
                              <i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            </span>
                            <input class="form-control" name="travelers" type="number"
                            id="travelers" max="5" min="1" step="1" value="1">
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div id="car" class="col-sm-4 order-sm-1 pb-5 pt-3">
                <div class="card mb-3">
                  <img src="images/pexels-photo-car.jpg" alt="car photo" class="card-img">
                  <div class="card-img-overlay">
                    <h1 class="card-title text-white h2">By Car</h1>
                  </div>
                </div>
                  <div class="col-12">
                    <div class="card bg-info mb-3">
                      <div class="form-group card-body">
                        <label class="h6" for="distance">Distance</label>
                        <div class="input-group">
                          <div class="input-group-prepend">
                            <span class="input-group-text">
                              <i class="fa fa-car" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            </span>
                            <input class="form-control" name="distance" type="number"
                            id="distance" max="5000" min="50" step="10" value="500">
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group card-body">
                        <label class="h6" for="mpg">MPG</label>
                        <div class="input-group">
                          <div class="input-group-prepend">
                            <span class="input-group-text">
                              <i class="fa fa-tint" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            </span>
                            <input class="form-control" name="mpg" type="number"
                            id="mpg" max="100" min="10" step="1" value="23">
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group card-body">
                        <label class="h6" for="ppg">PPG</label>
                        <div class="input-group">
                          <div class="input-group-prepend">
                            <span class="input-group-text">
                              <i class="fa fa-credit-card" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            </span>
                            <input class="form-control" name="ppg" type="number"
                            id="ppg" max="20" min=".10" step=".10" value="2.50">
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group card-body">
                        <label class="h6" for="hotel">Hotel</label>
                        <div class="input-group">
                          <div class="input-group-prepend">
                            <span class="input-group-text">
                              <i class="fa fa-bed"></i>
                            </span>
                            <select class="custom-select form-control" name="hotel" id="hotel">
                              <option value="100">Economy</option>
                              <option value="200">Business</option>
                              <option value="300">Luxury</option>
                            </select>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              <div id="plane" class="col-sm-4 order-sm-1 pb-5 pt-3">
                <div class="card mb-3">
                  <img src="images/pexels-photo-plane.jpg" alt="plane photo" class="card-img">
                  <div class="card-img-overlay">
                    <h1 class="card-title text-white h2">By Air</h1>
                  </div>
                </div>
                  <div class="col-12">
                    <div class="card bg-info mb-3">
                      <div class="form-group card-body">
                        <label class="h6" for="ticket">Ticket</label>
                        <div class="input-group">
                          <div class="input-group-prepend">
                            <span class="input-group-text">
                              <i class="fa fa-credit-card"></i>
                            </span>
                            <input class="form-control" name="ticket" type="number"
                            id="ticket" max="3000" min="50" step="50" value="500">
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group card-body">
                        <label class="h6" for="bags">Bags</label>
                        <div class="input-group">
                          <div class="input-group-prepend">
                            <span class="input-group-text">
                              <i class="fa fa-briefcase" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            </span>
                            <input class="form-control" name="checked_bags" type="number"
                            id="checked_bags" max="2" min="1" step="1" value="1">
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div id="update-row" class="row">
              <div id="update-column" class="col-12">
                <button id="update_button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Calculate</button>
              </div>
            </div>

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="travel-calculator.js"></script>
    </body>

</html>
```

The JavaScript is *supposed* to display a car or plane photo on top of the placeholder in the "change options" column alongside attached prices and instructions of whether to take a car or plane. But when I press the calculate button, literally nothing happens.

```
$(function () {
    "use strict";

    var pay_rate = 0;
    var travelers = 0;
    var distance = 0;
    var hotel = 0;

    var MAX_MILES = 300; // assume driving only 300 mi/day
    var WORK_HOURS = 8; // assume 8 hours of work/day

    function getCommonCosts() {

      pay_rate = Number($("#pay_rate").val());
      console.log("pay_rate " + pay_rate);

      travelers = Number($("#travelers").val());
      console.log("travelers " + travelers);
    }

    function getCarCosts() {

      var mpg = Number($("#mpg").val());
      console.log("mpg " + mpg);

      var ppg = Number($("#ppg").val());
      console.log("ppg " + ppg);

      distance = Number($("#distance").val());
      console.log("distance " + distance);

      hotel = Number($("#hotel").val());
      console.log("hotel " + hotel);

      var gallons = distance / mpg;
      console.log("gallons " + gallons);

      var mileage_cost = gallons * ppg;
      console.log("mileage_cost " + mileage_cost);

      var by_car_days = Math.ceil(distance / MAX_MILES);
      console.log("by_car_days " + by_car_days);

      var by_car_hotel = Math.floor(by_car_days) * hotel;
      console.log("by_car_hotel " + by_car_hotel);

      var by_car_pay =
      Math.ceil(by_car_days) * WORK_HOURS * pay_rate * travelers;

      console.log("by_car_pay " + by_car_pay);

      var total = mileage_cost + by_car_hotel + by_car_pay;
      console.log("(car) total " + total);

      return total;
    }

    function getFlightCosts() {

      var cost_per_bag = 50;
      console.log("cost_per_bag " + cost_per_bag);

      var flight_cost = Number($("#flight_cost").val());
      console.log("flight_cost " + flight_cost);

      var checked_bags = Number($("#checked_bags").val());
      console.log("checked_bags " + checked_bags);

      var by_flight_pay = WORK_HOURS * pay_rate * travelers;
      console.log("by_flight_pay " + by_flight_pay);

      var total = (flight_cost * travelers) +
      (checked_bags * cost_per_bag) + by_flight_pay;

      console.log("(plane) total " + total);

      return total;
    }

    function showResult(cost1, cost2) {
      var result_text = "";
      if (cost1 < cost2) {
        $("results img").attr(
          "src",
          "images/pexels-photo-car.jpg"
        );
        result_text = "Road Trip!";
      } else {
        $("results img").attr(
          "src",
          "images/pexels-photo-plane.jpg"
        );
        result_text = "Book a Flight!";
      }

      result_text = "<br/>";
      cost1 = Math.round(cost1 * 100) / 100;
      cost2 = Math.round(cost2 * 100) / 100;
      result_text += "Car: $" + cost1 + "<br/>";
      result_text += "Flight: $" + cost2 + "<br/>";
      $("results h1").html(result_text);
    }

    function updateResults() {
      getCommonCosts();

      var car_costs = getCarCosts() || 0;

      var flight_costs = getFlightCosts || 0;

      showResult(car_costs, flight_costs);
    }

    $("update_button").focus();
    $("update_button").click(function () {
      updateResults();
    });
});
```

Post-edit javascript:

> $(function () {
>       "use strict";

```
var pay_rate = 0;
var travelers = 0;
var distance = 0;
var hotel = 0;

var MAX_MILES = 300; // assume driving only 300 mi/day
var WORK_HOURS = 8; // assume 8 hours of work/day

function getCommonCosts() {

  pay_rate = Number($("#pay_rate").val());
  console.log("pay_rate " + pay_rate);

  travelers = Number($("#travelers").val());
  console.log("travelers " + travelers);
}

function getCarCosts() {

  var mpg = Number($("#mpg").val());
  console.log("mpg " + mpg);

  var ppg = Number($("#ppg").val());
  console.log("ppg " + ppg);

  distance = Number($("#distance").val());
  console.log("distance " + distance);

  hotel = Number($("#hotel").val());
  console.log("hotel " + hotel);

  var gallons = distance / mpg;
  console.log("gallons " + gallons);

  var mileage_cost = gallons * ppg;
  console.log("mileage_cost " + mileage_cost);

  var by_car_days = Math.ceil(distance / MAX_MILES);
  console.log("by_car_days " + by_car_days);

  var by_car_hotel = Math.floor(by_car_days) * hotel;
  console.log("by_car_hotel " + by_car_hotel);

  var by_car_pay =
  Math.ceil(by_car_days) * WORK_HOURS * pay_rate * travelers;
  console.log("by_car_pay " + by_car_pay);

  var total = mileage_cost + by_car_hotel + by_car_pay;
  console.log("(car) total " + total);

  return total;
}

function getFlightCosts() {

  var cost_per_bag = 50;
  console.log("cost_per_bag " + cost_per_bag);

  var flight_cost = Number($("#flight_cost").val());
  console.log("flight_cost " + flight_cost);

  var checked_bags = Number($("#checked_bags").val());
  console.log("checked_bags " + checked_bags);

  var by_flight_pay = WORK_HOURS * pay_rate * travelers;
  console.log("by_flight_pay " + by_flight_pay);

  var total = (flight_cost * travelers) +
  (checked_bags * cost_per_bag) + by_flight_pay;

  console.log("(plane) total " + total);

  return total;
}

function showResult(cost1, cost2) {
  var result_text = "";
  if (cost1 < cost2) {
    $("#results img").attr(
      "src",
      "images/pexels-photo-car.jpg"
    );
    result_text = "Road Trip!";
  } else {
    $("#results img").attr(
      "src",
      "images/pexels-photo-plane.jpg"
    );
    result_text = "Book a Flight!";
  }

  result_text = "<br/>";
  cost1 = Math.round(cost1 * 100) / 100;
  cost2 = Math.round(cost2 * 100) / 100;
  result_text += "Car: $" + cost1 + "<br/>";
  result_text += "Flight: $" + cost2 + "<br/>";
  $("results h1").html(result_text);
}

function updateResults() {
  getCommonCosts();

  var car_costs = getCarCosts() || 0;

  var flight_costs = getFlightCosts() || 0;

  showResult(car_costs, flight_costs);
}

$("#update_button").focus();
$("#update_button").click(function () {
  updateResults();
});
```

});

Comment: Have you checked your browser's console for errors?

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
$("results img")
```

This is not targeting an element. You need the pound sign to target that ID:

```
$("#results img")
```

So it should be:

```
$("#results img").attr(
  "src",
  "images/pexels-photo-car.jpg"
);
```

Please note, your listeners are also not targeting by ID. They all need to prefix with `#` for ID targeting, or `.` for class

Also, I think you have a typo:

```
var flight_costs = getFlightCosts || 0;
```

should probably be

```
var flight_costs = getFlightCosts() || 0;
```

But ultimately, your console will guide you through issues better than an eyeball audit. From a glance, those 2 things are going to be problematic. I can update this answer if more insight is posted after these are fixed.

Comment: Alright, I updated everything you said and have made some progress. However, it seems that no matter what values I input into the calculator, it comes out with the image for the plane, and also does not display the text showing the cost as it should. I will update the code on the question so you can see whats happening.

Comment: The code is updated, you can see it below my original post.

Comment: Dont forget to update all your element targets. here's one you missed for example: `$("results h1").html(result_text);`

Comment: Also, youre overwriting result_text here: `result_text = "<br/>";` so your flight or car text is doing nothing. You have a bunch of console logging happening here so you should be able to track down the cost of car and flight to see if by code the plane cost is always higher. There's a lot to look at here so aside these pointers a lot of it will be up to you to widdle down using the console logs.

Comment: Alright, I have fixed nearly everything. The only thing that is not working is the flight cost calculation which always comes out to 0. I will figure this one out myself. Your pointers did help me out a lot. Thanks for your time and patience, you have no idea how much easier my life just got because of it :p

Comment: No problem. glad it helped.

Comment: Update: Everything is now fixed and working. Thanks again man.